# ionic 2 show message template issue

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2, angularfire2

I am using ionic 2 and making chat app. The problem is:

```
 <div  class="message-wrapper" *ngFor="let item of items | async" >

      <div *ngIf="email === (item)?.email">                
             <div class="chat-bubble right">
                <div class="message"  autolinker>{{item.text}}</div>
                      <div class="message-detail">
                          <span am-time-ago="message.date" class="bold" >{{item.timestamp | MomentDate:"LLLL" }}</span>
                      </div>
                 </div> 
          </div>

            <div *ngIf="email !== (item)?.email">
                <div class="chat-bubble left">
                    <div class="message"  autolinker>{{item.text}}</div>
                        <div class="message-detail">
                            <span am-time-ago="message.date" class="bold">{{item.timestamp | MomentDate:"LLLL" }}</span>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
      <div class="cf"></div>
 </div>
```

[image]

As shown in the pic, if I add a new msg from the current user side message display below, the blue message right next side not after the light message can any way to display message below each other as in real chat...

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to change your HTML as below :

```
<div class="chat-bubble" [ngClass]="{right:email === (item)?.email, left:email !== (item)?.email}">
  <div class="message"  autolinker>{{item.text}}</div>
    <div class="message-detail">
      <span am-time-ago="message.date" class="bold" >{{item.timestamp | MomentDate:"LLLL" }}</span>
    </div>        
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thnks alot... 1 more Q i also want to add checkmark before the time ...in my push method where the message push to firebase am calling the than promise in which set the is_send property but not know how to implement it is any way to implement it,,,,,

Comment: Based on `is_send` value in `item` you can add class in your html to display checked icon.